# ActiveMQ not freeing up the disk storage for queue

Tags: spring, queue, activemq-classic

When throwing a significant amount of load to an ActiveMQ queue it seems to enqueue/dequeue messages as it's supposed to, but the storage remains full.

This causes the producer to block after some time, when the storage gets to 100%, which in turn causes the application to stop responding to requests.

This is the relevant activeMQ Spring configuration that we're using:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<!-- =====================================================
     Broker Configuration
     ===================================================== -->
<broker id="appEmbeddedBroker"
        xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        brokerName="${msg.embedded.broker.name}"
        persistent="true"
        dataDirectory="${msg.embedded.broker.data.directory}"
        useJmx="true" >

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                        <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                    </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext connectorPort="${msg.embedded.broker.jmx.port}" createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <levelDB directory="${msg.embedded.broker.db.directory}" />
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="10"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="${msg.embedded.broker.system.usage.store.usage}"/> <!-- Configured for 200Mb -->
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="${msg.embedded.broker.system.usage.temp.usage}"/> <!-- Configured for 40Mb -->
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Configure authentication; Username, passwords and groups -->
        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="app" password="${msg.embedded.broker.app.password}"
                                    groups="users"/>
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
    </plugins>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="tcp" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:${msg.embedded.broker.port}?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>

</broker>


<!-- =====================================================
     Client Connections
     ===================================================== -->

<bean id="embeddedAmqConnectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" depends-on="appEmbeddedBroker" >
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${msg.embedded.broker.url}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${msg.embedded.client.app.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${msg.embedded.broker.app.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="embeddedAmqPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="embeddedAmqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${msg.embedded.client.connection.pool.max}" />
</bean>
```

When querying the beans:

```
$>get QueueSize EnqueueCount DequeueCount                                                                                  

#mbean = org.apache.activemq:brokerName=app-embedded,destinationName=the.queue.name.local,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker:

QueueSize = 0;


EnqueueCount = 17821;


DequeueCount = 17821;
```

And:

```
#mbean = org.apache.activemq:brokerName=app-embedded,type=Broker:

StoreLimit = 209715200;


StorePercentUsage = 100;


TempLimit = 41943040;


TempPercentUsage = 0;
```

So, the question would be: **Why if all messages are getting dequeued we still see 100% of storage usage?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many reasons for this depending on you broker configuration and usage.  First thing to check is what the contents of your DLQ are, then look on the console for other destinations that are holding onto messages.  Due to the way things are propagated through the KahaDB journal logs it is possible that they create a chain that cannot be broken until you purge some other Queues or rollback any Transactions that are still inflight etc.

There is a [guide](http://activemq.apache.org/why-do-kahadb-log-files-remain-after-cleanup.html) on the ActiveMQ site that covers how to start debugging the situation that should help get you started.

Also try running the latest broker release, there are fixes that have gone into these components that try and address these sorts of situations.

Comment: Thanks @tim-bish for your answer. I looked at the console and none of the other queues/topics seemed to be holding onto messages, but still the storage is full. This was after another run. Also, the DLQ is not enabled. We're using an embedded ActiveMQ broker with the second to last release (5.13.2). Another thing to note is that we're not using KahaDB, we're using LevelDB instead.

Comment: Don't use LevelDB it has many issue and no upstream volunteers to maintain it.

Comment: We solved this problem a while ago, but marking this answer as the one that solved the issue because it was actually the DLQ that was filling up the space. We had a configuration that was making all (or most) messages go to the DLQ, even when they had been successfully processed.